# How do I return a database object as a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why does my application return `@users = User.where(acceptance: true)` as `#<User:0x007f9b0d444328>`?

when the console returns the same query as:

`[#<User id: 1, acceptance: "t", created_at: "2012-09-27 13:01:50", updated_at: "2012-09-27 13:02:52">]`

I want the users as a hash to pass to this sort of thing:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { render text: @users.to_csv }
end
```

Comment: I believe the console auto-inspect your objects and print them. Not sure though. In your application, you have to manually do a `puts @users.inspect`.

Comment: Ok yeah that's right. I've expanded the question though as it didn't really ask what I wanted it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@user.attributes
@users.map { |user| user.attributes }
```

This is a ruby hash of the fields in your database.  Then it will be up to you to encode it in JSON or CSV.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but I get an error e.g. `undefined method `attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9b0d462558>`

Comment: The error is outside of the scope of the question. This is the answer to the question as asked. Many thanks.